# electric android op: failed to make a map

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-electric, gmapping, android-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I run the android teleop on electric turtlebot. The android_teleop works fine, I can see the video and the teleop works without any problem.

I modified the file: turtlebot_bringup/mock_apps/turtlebot_apps.installed, add make_a_map and map_nav into the app chooser.

Then I try to use the make_a_map app. On my android tablet, there's no video or map image.

The log message is:

```
[/openni_camera] No devices connected.... Waiting for devices to be connected
Still waiting on map...
```

I can move the turtlebot around by touching the cross icon. Then I tried to save the map, there's an error message on android device:

```
 Naming map failed:
```

No map is saved.
I did installed map store by running: sudo apt-get install ros-electric-map-store

There's error message on the turtlebot netbook:

```
[ERROR] [1329741872.385404822]: Dynamic map getter service call failed.
```

And i can see openni_camera and slam_gmapping nodes are created:

```
rosnode list
/android1329726229488
/app_manager
/camera_throttle
/diagnostic_aggregator
/kinect_base_link
/kinect_base_link1
/kinect_base_link2
/kinect_base_link3
/kinect_laser
/kinect_laser_narrow
/map_saver
/master_sync_turtlebot3_7762_1685468291504748191
/master_sync_turtlebot3_7762_3382019221689062785
/mongo
/move_base
/openni_camera
/openni_manager
/pointcloud_throttle
/robot_pose_ekf
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
/slam_gmapping
/tf_throttle_for_android_gui
/turtlebot_laptop_battery
/turtlebot_node
```

But by running rxgraph, it seems that there's no node subscribing the openni_camera data.
Seems i can't upload the image file of rxgraph.

I've checked the latest code of turtlebot_teleop in mecurial repository. all the files i have are the latest version. And I did modified the file:
turtlebot_teleop//app/android_map_nav.launch:

```
<!--- Run AMCL --> 
<include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/config/amcl_turtlebot_map_from_topic.launch" />

to:

<!--- Run AMCL -->
<include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/config/amcl_turtlebot.launch" />
```

since file: amcl_turtlebot_map_from_topic.launch doesn't exist in electric turtlebot.

Anyone has any clue what might be the problem?

Thanks a lot!
/ma

**Update:**
I manually deleted the directory:

```
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot_apps/
```

Then checked out the latest source code in mercurial repository:

```
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps
```

Now the android map making app works. I can see the video stream, and the map image.
When saving the map, it poped "map saved as xxxx". It seems everything is good.

But when i start the map navigation app, there's video stream, and it shows "waiting for the map manager". On the turtlebot netbook, the log message is:

```
Still waiting on the map....
```

I added map making and map navigation app link to the App chooser. But there's no .app file so I don't know how to add "Android map manager" app into the App chooser.

I downloaded "Android map manager" from market, but it can't be started.
On the turtlebot netbook, I can't see where is the saved map file.

How to solve this problem?
Many thanks to all you for your help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27958/electric-android-op:-failed-to-make-a-map/) by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, can you do a source install of turtlebot_apps and see if the patches I just pushed work? This should:

a) enable breaker, which should fix the "no devices connected".

b) take care of the amcl_from_map_topic error (in the correct way, amcl_turtlebot is slightly different).

c) fix some issues with frame names.

I'm not sure on the "naming map failed" part, let's see if these changes can fix it.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) on 2012-02-20**:
@fergs - thank you very much. I'll do that. As @Ryan Hickman said, I'm also not sure how to do the source install. I compared my code with the mecurial repository in the silliest way: click files that i thought would be relevant one by one...